# Using CFBridgingRelease safely

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I'm relatively new to objective-c and I've still been grasping how its runtime works. In this case, I'm unsure about whether this code is safe:

```
CFErrorRef errorRef;
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &errorRef);
NSError * error = (NSError *)CFBridgingRelease(errorRef);

if (error != nil) {

}
```

Specifically, if `errorRef` is not referencing anything (I'm guessing `NULL`, not `nil`, right?), would this cast still be safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this code isn't safe. Per Apple's documentation:

> *error*: On error, contains error information.

That means that it's value on success is not guaranteed. You haven't initialized the variable, either — not that I'd trust `ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions` to leave it alone in success. The API documentation just doesn't guarantee that. (I *suspect* it would work, but this isn't the sort of thing you should rely on.)

You need to check if the function succeeded. Only if it failed should you try to access the error.

Safe code would be something like this:

```
CFErrorRef errorRef;
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &errorRef);
if (!addressBook) {
    NSError *error = (NSError *)CFBridgingRelease(errorRef);
}
```

Comment: I see. What about if I change the ownership for `addressBook`? Will the references in the array also change ownership? Should I iterate them all and cast individually?

Comment: The address book itself will hold its items. When you extract them, you'll be responsible for whatever memory management needs to be done for them -- probably taking ownership to ARC if they're in a Copy function. (If I remember right, they return a copied CFArray, and the array owns its objects. But you should check.)

Comment: @StevenFisher I think you should initialize errorRef with a NULL, because now it contains garbage, that might NOT be overwritten by ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions.

Comment: @MottiShneor If you initialize the errorRef to nil, you're essentially documenting through implication that "this errorRef will remain nil on success." But that's not true: Sometimes, Apple C functions like this mangle the errorRef. (It's a bug when it happens, but it's still be known to happen.) It really is only safe to access if there's an error, in which case `ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions` has set it. So I'd argue this is a case where leaving it uninitialized does the right thing: It tells you that it might still be uninitialized, depending on circumstances.